# Can JobDetail records be re-used, and how?

Tags: c#, quartz.net

Is there any way to create a new trigger on a JobDetail record which is in the database, but not in memory?  Specific use: I have jobs scheduled to run daily using a cron trigger.  Sometimes a particular day's job needs to be re-run with the same parameters.  I'd like to create a new simple trigger using the same JobDetail, since that's where the parameters are stored.  Reschedule() doesn't work, since it deletes the existing trigger.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

What I would do is the fetch the job from the database:

```
var myJob = Scheduler.GetJobDetail(jobName, groupName);
```

and use the function (which probably you've already used)

```
Scheduler.ScheduleJob(JobDetail jobDetail, Trigger trigger);
```

passing your new trigger.
You don't have to do much cause the run-time will fetch the new trigger from the DB after a few seconds and will run it.

UPDATE

There are two ways to add a trigger with Quartz.net

1) you can add a job and then the trigger:

```
Scheduler.AddJob(jobToSchedule, true);
Scheduler.ScheduleJob(triggerToSchedule);
```

2) you can schedule a trigger adding a job at the same time:

```
Scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobToSchedule, triggerToSchedule);
```

If you try to add a job and a trigger this way:

```
Scheduler.AddJob(jobToSchedule, true);
Scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobToSchedule, triggerToSchedule);
```

You get an **exception** which warns you the job already exists.

I would suggest you to clean the DB before making any test cause you might have some pending jobs. You can find a simple routine to clean it here:

```
        // unschedule jobs
        string[] groups = Scheduler.TriggerGroupNames;
        for (int i = 0; i < groups.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] names = Scheduler.GetTriggerNames(groups[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < names.Length; j++)
            {
                Scheduler.UnscheduleJob(names[j], groups[i]);
            }
        }

        // delete jobs
        groups = Scheduler.JobGroupNames;
        for (int i = 0; i < groups.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] names = Scheduler.GetJobNames(groups[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < names.Length; j++)
            {
                Scheduler.DeleteJob(names[j], groups[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Tried this before.  Maybe it works in Quartz, but in Quartz.net, GetJobDetail() works, but ScheduleJob() fails with "Couldn't store job: Unable to store Job with name: 'Job Name 1234' and group: 'Group Name', because one already exists with this identification."

Comment: I working with this stuff right now (Quartz.net) after one month of struggling. I'll update my answer to give you some more infos.

Answer (score 2):

In Quartz.net, I had to do this a little differently:

`Trigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger(triggerName, triggerGroup, newDateTime);
trigger.JobName = jobName;
trigger.GroupName = jobGroup;
Scheduler.ScheduleJob(trigger);`

That worked.

Comment: Cool, I basically did as Bruce stated here and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For [QuartzNet](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/), `Scheduler.GetJobDetail(jobName, groupName)` is not available.
Instead use :

```
    ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
    sched.Start();
    sched.GetJobDetail(new JobKey("job1", "group1"));
```

Additional reference: [GetJobDetail Method](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/topic277.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove all Jobs/Triggers in Quartz.Net 2.0 - this will do it for you:

```
        var groups = _scheduler.GetJobGroupNames().ToList();

        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            var jobKeys = _scheduler.GetJobKeys(GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupEquals(group)).ToList();

            foreach (var jobKey in jobKeys)
            {
                _scheduler.DeleteJob(jobKey);
            }
        }
```