# Quartz.net error when running job with ADOStore

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

Im using quartz.net in a asp.net mvc application.

Trying to configurate it to user ADOStore.

I have created the tables.

```
NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();

        properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "TestScheduler";
        properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "instance_one";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_";
        // if running MS SQL Server we need this
        properties["quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz";

        properties["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = "Server=.\\SQLExpress;Database=test;Trusted_Connection=True;";
        properties["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer-20";

// StdSchedulerFactory
        this.Initialize(properties);
```

When running the application im getting errormessages:

A first chance exception of type 'Quartz.ObjectAlreadyExistsException' occurred in Quartz.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Quartz.JobPersistenceException' occurred in Quartz.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Quartz.JobPersistenceException' occurred in Quartz.dll

When looking in the QRTZ_ tables QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS has one post in it for the job. The other tables is empty.

Any idea whats causing the problem here?

**UPDATE:**

```
public class UnitySchedulerFactory : StdSchedulerFactory
{
    private readonly UnityJobFactory unityJobFactory;

    public UnitySchedulerFactory(UnityJobFactory unityJobFactory)
    {
        NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();

        properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "TestScheduler";
        properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "instance_one";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_";
        // if running MS SQL Server we need this
        properties["quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz";

        properties["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = "Server=.\\SQLExpress;Database=189021;Trusted_Connection=True;";
        properties["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer-20";

        this.Initialize(properties);
        this.unityJobFactory = unityJobFactory;
    }

    protected override IScheduler Instantiate(QuartzSchedulerResources rsrcs, QuartzScheduler qs)
    {
        qs.JobFactory = this.unityJobFactory;            
        return base.Instantiate(rsrcs, qs);
    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
var scheduler = unityContainer.Resolve<IQuartzScheduler>();
scheduler.Run();
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is a link to the whole quartz solution:

http://1drv.ms/1o0rpg8

Quartz tables is created from following:

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit-Quartz/blob/master/setup_sql_server.sql

Global.asax:

```
var unityContainer = Infrastructure.Bootstrapper.Initialise();

var scheduler = unityContainer.Resolve<IQuartzScheduler>();
scheduler.Run();
```

The thing I'm trying to do is handle the misfiring with ADOstore so that the system can hanlde a restart or a crash.

Comment: Where are you initializing Quartz?

Comment: Have updated question

Comment: Was that what you meant?

Comment: You need to give us more information. Could you, please, upload your solution somewhere so we can have a look at it? Cheers.

Comment: Ok. Question updated again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're persisting your jobs (as you do) in a database you cannot create them all the time.
You have to check if they exists at the start-up.

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5485482/219406) for more details.

When **Quartz.Net** is initialized and you're using **AdoJobStore**, the scheduler fetches all the jobs/triggers save in the database.

In your `IQuartzScheduler.Run()` you should check if the job is present:

`this.Scheduler.GetJobDetail()`

You can use this bit of code to test if it works:

```
IJobDetail helloJob = null;
ITrigger helloTrigger = null;

helloJob = this.Scheduler.GetJobDetail(new JobKey("HelloJob", "MyGroup"));

if (helloJob == null)
{
    helloJob = JobBuilder.Create<Jobs.HelloJob>()
        .WithIdentity("HelloJob", "MyGroup")
        .RequestRecovery(true)
        // .StoreDurably(true)
        .Build();

    helloTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
         .WithIdentity("HelloTrigger", "MyGroup")
         .StartNow()
         .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.RepeatForever().WithIntervalInSeconds(20))
         .Build();

    this.Scheduler.ScheduleJob(helloJob, helloTrigger);
}

this.Scheduler.Start();
```

If you're using the latest Quartz.Net version there seem to be a problem with the database creation script.

I've noticed that the triggers don't fire. I've then created the database using the latest scripts from Quartz.Net repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/database/tables/tables_sqlServer.sql) and it works properly.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6504528/219406) as well. There are few more details on **Quartz.Net** + **AdoJobStore**.

Comment: Thank you! It's seams to work. One thing I dont understand though. When a job has been run ether when triggered as supposed to or with misfire instruction, how can one see that the job has actually run?

Comment: Best option is to configure Common.Logging and/or query the tables. QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS tables (for simple triggers) gives you the number of times the trigger has fired. I'd choose the log, anyway.